# ClassCastException when using a ViewPager with FragmentActivities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I've been trying to get 2 fragments work with a ViewPager with no success.. Here is the Main FragmentActivity which contains the ViewPager:

```
public class DownloadCenter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.download_center);
        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.DownloadCenter_viewPager);
        vp.setAdapter(new myAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));



    }

    public class myAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public myAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        Fragment[] fragmentArray = { Fragment.instantiate(DownloadCenter.this, Download_ImageQuality.class.getName()),
                Fragment.instantiate(DownloadCenter.this, Download_Tilawat.class.getName()) };

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            return fragmentArray[arg0];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentArray.length;
        }


    }
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/test.test.DownloadCenter}: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.test.Download_ImageQuality cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.test.Download_ImageQuality cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:388)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:363)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at test.test.DownloadCenter$myAdapter.<init>(DownloadCenter.java:29)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at test.test.DownloadCenter.onCreate(DownloadCenter.java:18)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-24 18:42:34.238: E/AndroidRuntime(4205):     ... 11 more
```

Download_ImageQuality header:

```
public class Download_ImageQuality extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.download_imagequality);
                 .... //REST OF CLASS
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) the following:

> ViewPager is most often used in conjunction with Fragment, which is a
> convenient way to supply and manage the lifecycle of each page. There
> are standard adapters implemented for using fragments with the
> ViewPager, which cover the most common use cases. These are
> FragmentPagerAdapter, FragmentStatePagerAdapter, FragmentPagerAdapter,
> and FragmentStatePagerAdapter; each of these classes have simple code
> showing how to build a full user interface with them.

As you can see it talks about Fragments not FragmentActivities, the main difference between both of them is that a Fragment are the one that goes inside a FragmentActivity. You can think of them as:

> FragmentActivity = Activity
>
> Fragment = View

**NOTE:** Is not exactly as this, this is just an approximation for make it clearer.

So the best for you in this case is to use a FragmentPagerAdapter and make all the content of your ViewPager a Fragment, and the you can handle the full life cycle inside each page.

Answer (score 3):

`Download_ImageQuality` needs to be a `Fragment`, not a `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: So Download_ImageQuality isnt musnt be an Activity??

Comment: @Omar: Correct. `FragmentPagerAdapter` uses `Fragment`s, not activities.

Comment: What if I extend PagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter, Will that work in order to keep Download_ImageQuality an Activity?

Comment: @Omar: No, it will not. A `ViewPager` cannot hold activities, by any means.